# Best way to set up a spawn system?

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

I was wondering what the best way to do this is. I want 2 sprites that fall from the top of the screen (landscape) at different times and once they reach the bottom they instantly respawn at a new random x coordinate back at the top and that continues for ever. Whats the best, cleanest way this can be done?

Comment: I havent really tried anything, just want to get some options first

Comment: Are they falling in a straight line?

Comment: Yep, maintain the same y value when falling